# Call function at end of for loop is not working as intended

Tags: python, function, loops

The following code is not working as intended when I call the next() function at end of for loop. For some reason only one item from the list is printed and it is always the same food (banana). When I remove the next() call at the end of the for loop, everything seems to run fine. Excuse the code, as I am sure there is a more efficient way to implement this, but could anyone explain why the function fails to work as intended?

I wanted this code to constantly loop back to the beginning of the function, add a random no of foods to shop list, and print them out after user presses enter button.

```
import random

food=["orange","banana","bread loaf","watermelon","cake","pudding"]

shop=[]

def next():
    day=input("press enter to start the next day:")
    if day==(""):
        rand=random.randrange(1,10)
        while rand > 0:
            shop.append(random.choice(food))
            rand-=1
            if rand <=0:
                shop.sort()
                for items in shop:
                    print(items)
                    next()
```

next()

Comment: Indentation error? `next()` is called in the loop that prints the items out - so only the first item gets printed out.

Comment: This is what I think is happening. but I am not sure where I can place next() so that it repeats the process without any type of error.

Comment: Just remove one indent on the line where you call `next()`

Comment: When I do this it 'kind of' works. The list keeps increasing in size way beyond randrange.

Comment: `next()` is the name of a Python built-in, you should not define your own function with the same name.

Comment: changing the function name did not help :(

Comment: Regardless, you should almost always avoid naming anything the same as a built-in because it can lead to strange hard to diagnose error and confuses folks who know the language.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort it out (mostly). Created two separate functions, but more importantly (i think) , changed the order of while loop and modified the if statement.

Also added a clear function for the list being appended. Everything except the list sorting function is working.

```
import random


food=["orange","banana","bread loaf","watermelon","cake","pudding"]
shop=[]


def nextday():
    rand=random.randrange(1,12)
    while rand > 0 :
        shop.append(random.choice(food))
        for i in shop:
            shop.sort()
            print(i)
            rand-=1
            if rand==0:
            day()

def day():
    print("")
    so=input("press enter to start the day: ")
    print("")
    if so==(""):
        shop.clear()
        nextday()
```

day()